# Find duplicate rows violating unique constraint on several fields

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

My CMS upgrade has the following query:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE locales_target ADD PRIMARY KEY (language, lid, plural)
```

It failed because of: "Duplicate entry '1-0' for key 'PRIMARY'".

I actually added the IGNORE myself on the query above, but it didn't help because table use the InnoDB engine, so the errors were not actually ignored.

This page shows how to find duplicate rows that would violate a unique contraint:
http://www.tocker.ca/2013/11/06/the-future-of-alter-table-ignore-syntax.html

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), emailaddress, count(*) as count FROM users 
GROUP BY emailaddress HAVING count >= 2;
```

but it does so for a unique field. How do I find duplicate rows with the 3-field primary key?

Edit: the original question still stands but here is some more information and more related questions:

1) what does '1-0' stand for in the error message? There are no rows where lid == 0!

2) The following query highlighted part of the problem:

```
mysql> select lid,  count(*) as count from france_locales_target group by lid having count != 1;
+------+-------+
| lid  | count |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     2 |
|    2 |     2 |
|    3 |     2 |
|    4 |     2 |
|    5 |     2 |
|    6 |     2 |
|    7 |     2 |
|    8 |     2 |
etc. etc.
```

Now, given that I use InnodDB and that IGNORE does not work, how would I go about gracefully deleting the duplicate rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily change ENGINE to MyISAM to let MySQL eliminate duplicates

```
ALTER TABLE locales_target ENGINE MyISAM;
ALTER IGNORE TABLE locales_target ADD PRIMARY KEY (language, lid, plural);
ALTER TABLE locales_target ENGINE InnoDB;
```

Comment: +1. Thanks. Simple! It worked like a charm! You answered the question in my edit just before I actually posted it! :)

Answer (score 5):

The same thing, except listing your three fields (`language`, `lid`, and `plural`) instead of just `emailaddress`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), language, lid, plural, count(*) as count
FROM locales_target
GROUP BY language, lid, plural HAVING count >= 2;
```

(Note: this assumes that you have some meaningful `id` field that you can select that really does uniquely identify the rows. If the problem is that your table has *no* truly unique keys, then that's trickier, but you could try just concatenating all your fields together and plopping it in the `id` slot.)

Comment: +1 Thanks. I posted the edit just before I saw your answer. The 'meaningful id' is actually lid. I didn't know we could group by several fields. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT language, lid, plural, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM locales_target
GROUP BY language, lid, plural
HAVING count > 1
```

should do the trick.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Same comment as for ruakh's answer. :) Thanks again.